# MVC 5 build failing on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I have been trying to get Visual Studio Team Services to compile and build my MVC 5 C# project. But I kept receiving the error messages below consistently:

> App_Start\BundleConfig.cs (2): The type or namespace name
>   'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?) Global.asax.cs (7): The type or
>   namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   App_Start\BundleConfig.cs (9): The type or namespace name
>   'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I went through similar issue posted on stackoverflow and tried to apply the suggested solutions but none of them worked! I have no idea what else could fix this issue to try. I appreciate it if you could shed some lights on it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the contents of App_Start\BundleConfig.cs?

Comment: Also try "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" from NuGet and make sure the DLL's are being copied to TFS

Comment: New build system works with asp.net5 stuff: more available here:  https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks  hopefully helps

Comment: Any solution to this ever found? Going back to days of coping resources and checking them into TFS is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that **Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization** and all of its dependencies are installed correctly.

Manage your Nuget Packages for the application and if it is showing as Installed, trying uninstalling and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually edit the .csproj for the project to fix the references, which were pointing to `../../OtherProject/packages/`, committed and rebuilt, then the build succeeded.

Comment: I'll dig up dinosaur but what would be correct path? I have problem as descried in this topic, but i can build app (and deploy it to azure) localy but i get similar error when building by team services. All nuget references ar added corectly (innmy opinion)